# Understanding of python requests script speed

Tags: python, performance, request

can someone explain me why my python script with approx 1400 requests lasts almost same time on my local machine with 15Mbit down speed and on cloud server with 500Mbit down speed? I really don't understand it.

Each request is approx 100Kb

Thank you

EDIT: I'm running script in PyCharm (local machine) and via ssh on cloud server

EDIT2: It takes 500seconds, am I doing something wrong?

EDIT3: source code [source code of script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d94782506560b24b5fec464401051e01)

Comment: You can essentially think of it as a car. If you're only driving your Ferrari for 1 second, you're not going to be any faster than the Honda Civic next to you. The remote server can also respond only so fast. Light can only respond so fast.

Comment: Without code its hard to say.  My initial guess would be that you're doing the requests sequentially instead of concurrently.  Also with 100kb requests you wont come near to saturating your 15Mbit download speed, so increasing the pipe won't help.

Comment: @EugeneK Agree. 1400 requests and 100kb each is really not that much.

Comment: Using @EugeneK's car example.  Concurrency would be like sending many cars at once instead of just one car many times.

Comment: See edits please.. this is just one script, I have another one with at least 150K requests and it lasts more than 6 hours.. soooo slooooow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500mbps isn't speed, it is bandwidth.  It means you can transfer 500mbps over the line.  It is just one factor of the "speed", another being latency which usually determined by the distance between the user and host.

The time it takes to reach the destination will be a combination of file size, bandwidth, and latency.  Theoretically being:

(file size / bandwidth) + latency

Bandwidth, however, will vary in practice due to other factors, mostly route congestion.

This means for large files, the time will be reduced by having more bandwidth but small files will be more noticeably impacted by latency.